# Is it true that $|cov(X, Y)| \leq 4|cov(|X|, |Y|)|$?

Tags: probability

If $X$, $Y$, and $XY$ are integrable random variables, is it true that $$|cov(X, Y)| \leq 4 |cov(|X|, |Y|)|$$

It's part of a problem where I already proved that $\forall (A, B)$, $$|P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B)| \leq \frac{1}{4}$$ and $$E(|XY|) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} P(|X| > x, |Y| > y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y $$

But I really don't know where to start with this one, and I don't even know if I'm looking for a counterexample or a proof...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider $(X,Y)$ which takes on two values: $(x,y)$ and $(-x,z)$, where $y \neq z$. Then $|X|$ is constant, so $\operatorname{Cov}(|X|,|Y|)=0$. What is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think you have to suppose $X$ and $Y$ non independant for this to work. Anyway you're totally right, it's false.

Comment: Just a little question, your proof uses discrete variables, is it okay to conclude that it's also false for non-discrete variables ?

Comment: @krirkrirk Yes, $X$ and $Y$ definitely have to be non-independent, which is definitely the case in my example. My proof can't be adapted directly to make both $X$ and $Y$ non-discrete. $Y$ could be pretty much whatever as long as it's not constant, but it was important that $|X|$ be constant and $X$ is not. I'm not sure how to prove the result when $|X|$ is non-constant, but I wouldn't be surprised if it were possible.

Comment: Alright, thanks again !

Comment: @krirkrirk I should actually clarify the notation a bit: "$(X,Y)$ takes on two values" $(x,y)$ and $(-x,z)$" means that the actual pair takes on those two values, in other words $X=x$ iff $Y=y$ and $X=-x$ iff $Y=z$. So the non-independence is very much built into the construction.